# best javascript engine for cross platform desktop app

Tags: javascript, c++, html, qt

I am going to create a desktop app, with C++ as backend, Html/JS as UI. for now, it just hosted by QtWebKit to cross platform, maybe in future, may be hosted on line.

Is QtWebKit is a good approach? the interface will be signal/slot, not sure whether it easy to port to other javascript engine when porting to website?

any ideas on this? thanks in advance.

Comment: True, too generic i think. Got some basic ideas from the answers anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you keep each slot 'simple' (as in literally just doing UI stuff with your business logic being  handled in an instanced business logic class), it should be trivial to port this to the web later on.

I would suggest you NOT do it this way if you're going to be trying to port it to the web. The reasoning being that you're going to have to re implement your backend(which currently will be done in c++ in your app) in a server language (either php, .NET, python, RoR, etc...).

If you're looking for an 'easy' way to do this work once for a web interface AND a cross-platform Qt c++ app, I'd look to doing all of your business logic at a server app while still using the QtWebkit as your front-end. It's trivial with Qt to do HTTP requests(GET and POST) and get/parse json/html.

This will allow you to very easily replace the slot mechanism with any JS event driven framework (I use jQuery). This will also not force you to 'port' the back-end logic.

This also has the additional benefit of being able to be used for mobile applications if you're ever thinking about going that way as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully used Mozilla's SpiderMonkey in a cross-platform C++ application (32 and 64 bit Windows and Ubuntu) and it worked out quite well.  I don't really understand your question details/description though...